# Woo-commerce Booking - Fetch all available bookings based on Time Range

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm trying to fetch bookings based on time availability in wocommerce bookings by passing the time selection in below format:

> 2019-08-26 08:00 - 2019-08-26 11:00

```
    $available_blocks = $booking_form->product->get_available_blocks( array(
                                    'blocks' => $blocks_in_range,
                                    'from' => $from,
                                    'to' => $to));

    foreach ( $available_blocks as $check ) {
                 if ( true === $booking_form->product->check_availability_rules_against_date( $check, '' )){
                      //Custom Added to fetch only blocks in selected range
                      if( $from >= reset($available_blocks) && $to <= end($available_blocks)){
                             $matches[] = $post_id;
                             break; // check passed
                            }
                       }
              }
```

But, it's only working when I pass time in Hour only format(10:00 AM), When I add minute(10:30 AM) it is not returning any available bookings.

Full function for reference.

```
/**
     * Get all available booking products
     *
     * @param string $start_date_raw YYYY-MM-DD format
     * @param string $end_date_raw YYYY-MM-DD format
     * @param int $quantity Number of people to book
     * @param string $behavior Whether to return exact matches
     * @return array Available post IDs
     */
    function get_available_bookings( $start_date_raw, $end_date_raw, $quantity = 1, $behavior = 'default' ) {
        $matches = array();

        // Separate dates from times
        $start_date = explode( ' ', $start_date_raw );
        $end_date = explode( ' ', $end_date_raw );


        // If time wasn't passed, define defaults.
        if ( ! isset( $start_date[1] ) ) {
            $start_date[1] = '00:00';
        }

        $start = explode( '-', $start_date[0] );


        $args = array(
            'wc_bookings_field_resource' => 0,
            'wc_bookings_field_persons' => $quantity,
            'wc_bookings_field_duration' => 1,
            'wc_bookings_field_start_date_year' => $start[0],
            'wc_bookings_field_start_date_month' => $start[1],
            'wc_bookings_field_start_date_day' => $start[2],
        );

        // Loop through all posts
        foreach ( $this->product_ids as $post_id ) {
            if ( 'product' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
                $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

                if ( is_wc_booking_product( $product ) ) {

                    // Grab the duration unit
                    $unit = $product->is_type( 'accommodation-booking' ) ? 'night' : $product->get_duration_unit();


                    // Support time
                    if ( in_array( $unit, array( 'minute', 'hour' ) ) ) {
                        if ( ! empty( $start_date[1] ) ) {
                            $args['wc_bookings_field_start_date_time'] = $start_date[1];
                        }
                    }

                    if ( 'exact' === $behavior ) {  
                        $duration = $this->calculate_duration( $start_date_raw, $end_date_raw, $product->get_duration(), $unit );        
                        $args['wc_bookings_field_duration'] = $duration;
                    }

                    $booking_form = new WC_Booking_Form( $product );
                    $posted_data = $booking_form->get_posted_data( $args );

                    // All slots are available (exact match)
                    if ( true === $booking_form->is_bookable( $posted_data ) ) {
                        $matches[] = $post_id;
                    }

                    // Any slot between the given dates are available
                    elseif ( 'exact' !== $behavior ) {
                        $from = strtotime( $start_date_raw );
                        $to = strtotime( $end_date_raw );

                        $blocks_in_range = $booking_form->product->get_blocks_in_range( $from, $to );

                        // Arguments changed in WC Bookings 1.11.1
                        $available_blocks = $booking_form->product->get_available_blocks( array(
                            'blocks' => $blocks_in_range,
                            'from' => $from,
                            'to' => $to
                        ) );


                        foreach ( $available_blocks as $check ) { 
                            if ( true === $booking_form->product->check_availability_rules_against_date( $check, '' )){
                                    $matches[] = $post_id;
                                    break; // check passed
                                }
                            }
                        }             

                }
            }
        }

        return $matches;
    }
```